# "Source paper" of the method Reduction in library Sumy

Tags: python, automatic-summarization

Does anybody know or can help me to find the source paper of the method "Reduction" of the library "sumy"?

This method is here: [Reduction](https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy/blob/main/sumy/summarizers/reduction.py) where it says that it is based on [here](https://github.com/adamfabish/Reduction/tree/master/Source), but in none of these places I am able to find the source.

At this [description](https://miso-belica.github.io/sumy/summarizators.html), it only says that: "Graph-based summarization, where a sentence salience is computed as the sum of the weights of its edges to other sentences. The weight of an edge between two sentences is computed in the same manner as TextRank."

The entire library is said to be based on this [thesis](https://dspace.vutbr.cz/handle/11012/53529). However, it is in germany. I tried to find, but I was not able to do that because of language barrier.

Comment: Fyi the thesis is not in German but in Czech, in case you want to try Google Translate. Apparently there's [no other publication by this author](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=michal+belica), so this might be the only solution.

Comment: You are right! I searched for the method there but I did not find!